# Can I safely use multiple mongo cursors at once in ruby?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, cursor

Can you tell me if following code is safe and there is no risk that some documents may be missed?
The idea behind the code is to process multiple data sets (obtained for multiple queries), but spend at most n seconds in each collection.

Example: for two sets of data `[1,2,3,4]`, `[A,B,C,D]`, lets say each item processing time is 5 seconds and `took_too_much_time` returns `true` every 10 secs, I want to process 1,2, then A,B, then 3,4, then C,D.

On a small amount of data everything is working well but after switching to bigger set (tens of queries and thousands of documents), I'm missing some documents. Would be really great if ou could confirm or deny that below code may be the reason.

```
cursors = []
queries.each do |query|
    collection.find(query, {timeout: false}) { |c| cursors << c }
end

while(cursors.any?)
    cursors.each do |c|
        c.each do |document|
            process_document(document)
            break if took_too_much_time
        end
    end

    cursors = remove_empty_cursors(cursors)
end
```

Comment: is this mongoid or the mongodb ruby driver?

Comment: I use mongoid for mongo connection.